# Ubuntu server failing daily

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, ubuntu-10.04

Symptoms:

- Server becomes unresponsive - Increase in load, all services stop
- Loss of connectivity - Ping/SSH
- Flush MySQL hosts after reboot - As MySQL refuses new connections
- Intermittent Apache crashes
- Generally happens early morning hours - 2 days of the week are however excluded

Changes made:

- Updated the OS - to Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS
- Not sure if the MySQL server was also updated in the process
- Current MySQL version - mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.63, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.1
- Updated Plesk from 10.4.4 Update #47 to 11.0.9 Update #23
- Rebooted on almost daily basis
- All crons stopped for the times corresponding to the server crashes
- Created a MySQL log to monitor the lock times on queries

Possible causes:

- Failing hardware
- Incorrect software configuration (MySQL, Apache etc)

Responsibilities:

- Small webserver
- Runs our billing system - WHMCS
- Responsible for CRONs
- Bulk-email solution - No delivery times coincide with server crashes

Proposed solutions:

- Move machine over to VM
- Format and restore the Plesk server backup and take it from there?

Side notes:

- Seems to be a general Apache failure across all our linux servers - Intermittent problem
- Are we doing something fundamentally wrong in the Apache config? (I understand that this is a secondary question, just making sure that it isnt possibly holding any relevance)

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never use prtg, but if I am reading the chart correctly, you are running out of memory. And your server problem last, if not completely crashed, from around 1am to 2-3am. Though the problem seem to start from 12am. Your server load just jump to the roof right at that moment.

During that period of time:

- Chart **Memory (Swap) Free 2**, swap usage build up to 6G-7G, that is
  a lot comparing with 1G of physical ram
- Chart **Memory (Real) Free 2** / **SNMP Linux Meminfo 2**, all ram are used

Though memory seems to be the main cause. It is possible (or part of the problem) caused by lack of cpu power. As previous request still being process, new request comes in, more and more request pile up in the server.

I would suggest increasing memory, and also find out what is being run at 12am.

Comment: It seems that no crons are run at that time. So we have eliminated the possibility of crons. There are 2 RAM slots still open. will look at upgrading the RAM and see if the problem is resolved

Comment: What about backup? How is storage configure? Is it iscsi/nfs?

Comment: It is isci. The backup runs at 1 AM in the morning. Upgraded the 2 GB of RAM to 4GB.

Comment: Any improvement? How is backup done? (from san/iscsi / from server / from another server) Also is there timezone/day light saving difference between backup config and the server? If they are off by 1hr ...

Comment: There has been an improvement yes. From server to another server, it does have a private/backup network interface. No there isnt (daylight savings). We are in South Africa.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to do some real analysis of the root cause(s).

- Configure and monitor apache's [**server-status**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_status.html) to get a feel for web server load.
- Set up system monitoring for basic metrics (CPU, memory, disk activity) to see where exactly the bottleneck is
- Monitor `dmesg` closely, both when you restart and during normal running, to verify there are no obvious hardware issues.

Once you have a few days' worth of solid data, you can take the next step (the one you thought you were taking now - ask for advice.)

Comment: We make use of PRTG to monitor the server. So we looked at these (PRTG) logs in order to find a pattern, but with no luck. We logged the MySQL query times and then tried to match long query times with server load and found no link. What is the best way to monitor dmesg? Run a few terminals with dmesg | grep -i memory etc?

Comment: You're going to have to provide these results, of course.

Comment: http://postimage.org/image/85q1vqgy9/full/ - this should give you a broad idea. I can provide any detailed logs if need be

Comment: Ugh, that's far too small to be of any use.

Comment: Can surely zoom in, pic is in high res

Comment: ...it's the size I see it on my screen.

Answer (score 1):

99.9% of the time on a setup like the one you have it's misconfiguration of mysql on a box that is too small to handle the amount of connections assigned.  A very *average* setup of mysql sets the connection limit to 200, each connection that comes in usually takes between 10 ~ 100mb depending on the queries / caching etc.

I've seen many companies setting their connection limits way over the maximum memory that the actual machine has based on how they configure it.  When MySQL tries to address the memory and gets assigned to swap instead it causes the system to crash.  You can usually see traces in dmesg.

Post your MySQL configuration + number of cpu's/vcpus and memory, likelyhood it's probably MySQL that is configured incorrectly.  The documentation is hard to follow for mysql but there are some helper scripts to give you an idea.  I'll try to find one of the ones I've used in the past that is the most accurate unfortunately i don't recall the script name off the top of my head.

Also keep in mind that looking at mysql logs will not show you the true story.